# String manipulation in a column in an Oracle table

Tags: database, string, oracle

One of my tables' column contains names, for example as `"Obama, Barack"` (with double quotes). I was wondering if we can do something to make it appear as `Barack Obama` in the tables. I think we can do it with declaring a variable but just could not manage to find a solution.

And yes as this table contains the multiple transactions of the same person we also end up with having multiple rows of `"Obama, Barack"`... a data warehouse concept (fact tables).

Comment: If you're really serious about doing this you can move everything after a comma to the front of the column, `instr` should help. Please don't though. Have two columns, `firstname` and `lastname` and then you can combine them however you want.

Comment: Oh yeah, and watch out for Ms. Jr. Dr. III, Esq., etc.  Don't forget middle names.

Comment: @John, thanks, was trying not to bore there's loads more. The odd person who insists on calling themselves, depending on where you live, Reverend Doctor John H. Patrick Smith BA PHD, for instance. so you'll want `pre title` and `post title` as well as middle name.

Comment: Hi, changing it to two columns as mentioned by Ben is part of design phase which i am surely not part of. so i m just left on my own to figure it out. :(

Answer (score 1):

What @Ben has said is correct. Having two columns one for first name and one for last name is correct.

However if you wish to update the entire database as it is you could do...

```
  /*This will swap the order round*/
  UPDATE TableName SET NameColumn = SUBSTRING(NameColumn, 1, CHARINDEX(',',NameColumn))+SUBSTRING(NameColumn, CHARINDEX(',', NameColumn),LEN(NameColumn)-CHARINDEX('"', NameColumn,2))

  /*This will remove the quotes*/
  UPDATE TableName SET NameColumn = REPLACE(NameColumn, '"', '')
```

Edit:- but as I can't see your data you may have to edit it slightly. But the theory is correct. See here http://www.technoreader.com/SQL-Server-String-Functions.aspx

Comment: The OP used the tag 'oracle', so I'm not sure how relevant an answer about SQL Server is.

Comment: Hi Eddie.

Thanks for ur reply. This is regarding oracle only.. i tried to fire the above query with lil oracle updates as substr,instr and length.. however it still threw me "ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis".. query looks good to me but still unable to find the resolution

moreover the changing to two columns as mentioned by Ben is part of design phase which i am surely not part of. :(

Regards!

Answer (score 1):

From the question I assume you want to:

- Remove the quotes
- Remove the comma
- Swap the names

So Regexp_replace is probably your best bet

```
UPDATE tablename
SET    column_name = REGEXP_REPLACE( column_name, '^"(\w+), (\w+)"$', '\2 \1' )
```

So `regexp_replace` is changing the column value as long as it matches the pattern exactly. What the parts of the expression are

- `^"` means it must start with a double quote
- `(\w+)` means immediately followed by a string of 1 or more alphanumeric characters. This string is then *saved* as the variable `\1` because its the first set of `()`
- `,` means immediately followed by a comma and a space
- `(\w+)` means immediately followed by a string of 1 or more alphanumeric characters. This string is then *saved* as the variable `\2` because its the second set of `()`
- `"$` means immediately follwed by a double quote which is the end of the string
- `\2 \1` is the replacement string, the second *saved* string followed by a space followed by the first *saved* string

So anything which does not exactly match these conditions will not be replaced. So if you have an leading or traling spaces, or more than one space after the comma, or many other reasons the text will not be replaced.

A much more flexible (maybe too flexible) option could be:

```
UPDATE tablename
SET    column_name = REGEXP_REPLACE( column_name, '^\W*(\w+)\W+(\w+)\W*$', '\2 \1' )
```

This is similar but effectively makes the quotes and the comma optional, and deals with any other leading or trailing pubctuation or whitespace.

- `^\W*` means must start with **zero** or more non-alphanumberics
- `(\w+)\W+(\w+)` means two alphanumberic strings separated by one or more non-alphanumerics. The two strings are saved as described above
- `\W*$` means must then end with **zero** or more non-alphanumberics

More info on regexp in oracle is here

- http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/ap_posix.htm
- http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_regexp.htm

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply..
yes all the three things i want to do. :)

m not so familar with the regex exp.. did u mean to fire the above ? as i did the same, the query did fire successfully but still the names were unchanged..

Comment: Yep the above should have worked. I'll explain it in the answer and then add a more flexible version